# How to take jpeg image inputs from a folder in linux one by one?

Tags: linux, image, opencv, input

I have written a image processing program in linux using opencv. Currently I am giving input image as a argument (argv[1]) . I want to take mutiple images one by one from a folder which contains many jpeg images. My plan is to make it like a slide show of processed image.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `glob` module to get list of every jpg file in directory ?

```
import glob
import sys
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
file_list = glob.glob('%s/*.jpg' % sys.argv[1])
for i in file_list:
     frame = cv2.imread(i)                                                  
     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
     cv2.waitKey(1000) '''time out for 1 sec'''
```

Where, argv[1] is path of the directory. Once you've a list of files, you can run a loop and run a slideshow like mentioned above.

Please note that, this is the quick implementation of your problem in Python. You can very well convert it in c++.

Hope it helps.